# Upgrade to varnish v4

Tags: varnish, varnish-vcl

We've upgraded varnish v3 to v4 and I currently working on converting my vcl.

In the v3 version we've used inline C to set and read headers with following functions:

```
VRT_GetHdr(sp, HDR_REQ, header);    
VRT_SetHdr(sp, HDR_REQ, header, value , vrt_magic_string_end);
```

However in version 4 those functions are are slighty changed.
After some searching we've found that's we need to use a kind of a structure to define a header.

```
VCL_HEADER hdrdef;
hdrdef->where = HDR_REQ;
hdrdef->what = "\005Test:";
```

When using this we get a compiler fail with message that it cannot assign to a read only object.
Do somebody know how we can utilize/fill this structure?

Thanks in advance!

Kristof

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
C{
static const struct gethdr_s VGC_HDR_REQ_hdrdef = { HDR_REQ, "\005Test:" };
}C

C{
VRT_SetHdr(ctx, &VGC_HDR_REQ_hdrdef, value, vrt_magic_string_end);
}C
```

See: https://github.com/varnish/Varnish-Cache/blob/master/bin/varnishtest/tests/r01406.vtc